# how to increase the number of resulting places for google-nearby-places-web-service, as i always get up to 20 places only

Tags: google-maps, web-services, google-places-api

i only get 20 place nearby no matter i expand the range area 500, 2000, 3000 in meters just appear new places but it doesn't add to the old one replace some so always have at max of 20 place every time

i tried running the api on other devices and expanded the search area smae problem remains

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=30.050203,31.221214&radius=1500&key=SOMEKEY

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=30.050203,31.221214&radius=3000&key=SOMEKEY

expected results to have as much as places near me so i expect when i expand the search area to 3000 meters instead of 1500 to find more plcaes
BUT i always have 20 places no matter what !!

Answer (score 2):

Places API Nearby Search returns up to 20 establishment results per query, regardless of the radius value you pass to it.

Using `pagetoken` you can get up to 60 places, split across 3 pages (3 queries).

Check out Google's documentation to learn more: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchPaging

Hope this helps.